# Order of events in AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am implementing custom authorization in one my MVC project, completely understood purpose of each events listed below but not figure out the order which they will be fired. Also tried to debugging to understand flow, observed only OnAuthorization getting fired.

This my understanding:

```
OnAuthorization
    {
        // for authentication based on Role. 
        AuthorizeCore
        {

        }
        //UnAuthorized request.
        HandleUnauthorizedRequest
        {
        }
    }
```

Can some help me in understanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we override OnAuthorization, AuthorizeCore and HandleUnauthorizedRequest methods in our custom authorization class, then it will call OnAuthorization method, then if we call base.OnAuthorization(filterContext) method in OnAuthorization method, then it will call AuthorizeCore method, if return false, then it will call HandleUnauthorizedRequest method.

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        //filterContext.result = new redirectresult(constants.notifyurl);
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom attribute by inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute. Then override AuthorizeCore and HandleUnauthorizedRequest, and do your custom authorization logic there. If AuthorizeCore returns false, HandleUnauthorizedRequest will fire.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //Do custom authorization logic
        //Check for role here too

        if(authenticated && hasRole)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (authenticated)
        {
            //user was authenticated but lacks proper role
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                            new RouteValueDictionary 
                    {
                        { "action", "AccessDenied" },
                        { "controller", "Account" }
                    });
        }
        else
            //this will just send the user back to the Login method in the Account Controller
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Wooters. when OnAuthorization will be fired? before /after AuthorizeCore. Is there any relation between AuthorizeCore and AuthorizeCore,HandleUnauthorizedRequest as you explained above between AuthorizeCore and HandleUnauthorizedRequest.